# How do I set the title for the back button on a Nav Bar in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have to remove the title on the back button in several pages. I tried with this code and it works fine.

```
private void OnBtn ()
    {           
        var nav = (Page)ViewFactory.CreatePage<DebugViewModel, DebugPage> ();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (nav, true);
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton (nav, true);
        NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle (nav, "");
        ((MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync (nav);
    }
```

But in some other place of the code I have this and it doesn't set the title to an empty string.

```
this.SettingsPageCommand = new Command (() => {
            this.IsBusy = true;
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (settingsPage, true);
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton (settingsPage, true);
            NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(settingsPage, "");
            ((MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync (settingsPage);
            //((MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage).IsPresented = false;
            this.IsBusy = false;
        }, () => !this.IsBusy);
```

I'm trying to avoid making a renderer as I want to keep as much shared code as possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running that code from within  `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title property of content page is used on next page as title of back button.

Try Setting  this.Title="" on  previous page of settings page

Answer (score 2):

@hrishi's answer is correct, however if you wish to have different text shown in the Title Bar (this.Title) than shown for the Back button text on subsequent pages you can alternatively call the following method. You would call this in the constructor for the page whose title should be different on the back button:

NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "CustomText");

Typically I only set Title unless it needs to be different when shown for back button (ex: shorter text) in which case I set both Title and call the above method with the alternative back button text.